# java design pattern for for decoupling task completion and execution of next

Tags: java, design-patterns

I implemented a wrapper for a queue that holds incoming tasks.  Every time a task is executed, a callback is called to the wrapper's owning class for the the actual execution (doSomething()).
This implementation doesn't look good, because as long as there are still items in the queue, the callbacks will start chaining together and grow the stack.  Is there a common design pattern to decouple the completion of the previous task and execution of the next task?

```
    public void executeCallback(Task task) {
      switch(task.type()) {
        case TASK_TYPE1:
          doSomething();
          break;
        case TASK_TYPE2:
          doSomethingElse();
      }
      queueWrapper.executeNextTaskInQueue(); //doesn't look too good
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just wait for the task call to return?

Comment: Are the tasks executed using some kind of `Executor`? Maybe you could use a `ManagedTaskExecutor` and listen to the completion there, followed by executing the next task?

Comment: thanks for getting back.  the issue i'm having is the completion of some of the tasks occur via reception of a broadcast message.  i'm wondering if there is a centralized way to manage signals indicating task completion from mutilple places.

Comment: thx..looks like executor is the way to go